# select with other objects than sockets on windows

Tags: windows

I'm facing an issue doing a select() call waiting on a socket + pipe.

I know there are already some topics on that but I have read lots of things and their opposite and I can't figure out what is the best solution for my problem.

The best for me would be to use WaitForMultipleObjects() listening on these two objects but when I try to call it only on the WSAEvent object, it fails and last error catch is code 6 (Invalid Handle).

```
WSAEVENT sockEvent = WSACreateEvent();
sockEvent = WSAEventSelect(fd, sockEvent, FD_WRITE);
HANDLE *pHandles = &sockEvent;
DWORD dwEvent = WaitForMultipleObjects(1, pHandles, FALSE, amqp_time_ms_until(deadline));
  switch (dwEvent) 
    { 
      // ghEvents[0] was signaled
      case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: 
        // TODO: Perform tasks required by this event
        return AMQP_STATUS_OK;

        // ghEvents[1] was signaled
      case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: 
        // TODO: Perform tasks required by this event
        return AMQP_STATUS_POLL_EXTERNAL_WAKE;

      case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        return AMQP_STATUS_TIMEOUT;

        // Return value is invalid.
      default: 
        return AMQP_STATUS_SOCKET_ERROR; 
    }
```

So WaitForMultipleObjects doesn't seems to Work with WinSocks events, however I have already seen some examples on the net working with it.
And the of WSACreateEvent documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says this :

> Windows Sockets 2 event objects are system objects in Windows
>   environments. Therefore, if a Windows application wants to use an
>   auto-reset event rather than a manual-reset event, the application can
>   call the CreateEvent function directly.

This doesn't mean that WSAEvent are based on regular windows events ? If it's the case why it doesn't work with WaitForMultipleObjects ? The doc says it can handle regular events.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
sockEvent = WSAEventSelect(fd, sockEvent, FD_WRITE);
```

You're overwriting the event handle!  ([As documented,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx) the return value for WSAEventSelect is either 0 or SOCKET_ERROR.  It is not a new event handle.)

Try something like

```
if (WSAEventSelect(fd, sockEvent, FD_WRITE) != 0) return SOCKET_ERROR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the declaration of `WSAEVENT` revealed that `WSAEVENT` is simply an alias for `HANDLE`. This explains the note of the `WSACreateEvent` documentation you added to your post. So `WSACreateEvent` simply creates a manual reset event by calling `CreateEvent(..., TRUE, FALSE, ...);`.

Therefore an event returned by `WSACreateEvent` has to work along with `WaitForMultipleObjects(..)`.

According to the code you've posted I cannot see any reason why `WaitForMultipleObjects(..)` should return "invalid handle" when supplied with an event returned by `WSACreateEvent`...

It may be though that pipes do not work with `WaitForMultipleObjects(..)`. I remember having problems with that a long time ago but I cannot remember the details right now. But maybe it is another place to start digging...

Here is the code of my little test application which creates two threads (one event thread signalling a normal event and a simple TCP/IP server sending data). In the main loop a connection to the server is established and signalled events are processed.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib");


#define SERVER_PORT  5000

HANDLE hSomeEvent;
HANDLE hSocketEvent;


DWORD WINAPI eventThread(LPVOID pData)
{
   while (1)
   {
      SleepEx(2250, FALSE);

      SetEvent(hSomeEvent);
   }
   return (0);
}

DWORD WINAPI serverThread(LPVOID pData)
{
   SOCKET listener;
   struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
   int size;
   SOCKET client;


   listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (listener == INVALID_SOCKET)
   {
      printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
   }

   sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   sockaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
   if (bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr , sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
      printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
   }

   listen(listener, 1);

   while (listener)
   {
      size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
      client = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, &size);

      printf("client connected\n");

      while (client != INVALID_SOCKET)
      {
         SleepEx(5000, FALSE);

         if (send(client, "hello\0", 6, 0) != 6)
         {
            closesocket(client);
            shutdown(client, 2);
            client = INVALID_SOCKET;
         }
      }

      SetEvent(hSomeEvent);
   }
   return (0);
}



int main()
{
   WSADATA wsaData;
   HANDLE events[2];
   DWORD result;
   SOCKET s;
   struct hostent *hp;
   struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
   int len;
   char buff[1024 * 16];
   HANDLE *evtPtr;


   WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

   hSocketEvent = WSACreateEvent();
   //hSocketEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "socket_event");
   hSomeEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "some_event");


   CreateThread(NULL, 0, eventThread, NULL, 0, &result);
   CreateThread(NULL, 0, serverThread, NULL, 0, &result);


   s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
   {
      printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
   }

   hp = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
   sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)hp->h_addr);
   sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   sockaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
   if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)))
   {
       closesocket(s);
       printf("Could not connect socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
   }

   WSAEventSelect(s, hSocketEvent, FD_READ);

   do
   {
      //events[0] = hSocketEvent;
      //events[1] = hSomeEvent;
      //result = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, events, FALSE, 1000);

      evtPtr = &hSocketEvent;
      result = WaitForMultipleObjects(1, evtPtr, FALSE, 1000);
      switch (result)
      {
         case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
            printf("hSocketEvent is signalled!\n");

            len = recv(s, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
            printf("   %d bytes received\n", len);

            WSAResetEvent(hSocketEvent);
            break;

         case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            printf("hSomeEvent is signalled!\n");
            break;

         case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            printf("timeout\n");
            break;

         default:
            printf("error = %d\n", GetLastError());
            break;
      }
   }
   while (1);

   printf("\n\nend.");
   getch();

   return (0);
}
```

Note that if you use `WSACreateEvent` you have to manually reset the event after readinng the data (otherwise `WaitForMultipleObjects(..)` will go nuts).

Comment: Infact I was thinking unix dev and the pipe was just for waking up select() from another thread. On Windows it's just a simple event so finally didn't need a pipe for that. But thank's for helping ! :)